# Extract Email Address from eml files

Tags: macos, eml

Hi I have a folder on my MacBookPro with a bunch of eml files from my outlook 2011.  I'm trying to get the from email addresses out of them, but all the links I've found require I buy software or code in something like C#.

Is it really this difficult?  All I'm trying to do is get an email list here from a bunch of old emails.

I know some python, R, and SQL.  If anyone can give me some tips on an easy way to pull the from email addresses in to a text file or convert the eml files in to a csv, without buying software or coding in C#, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: do you have php installed ? you can check that by opening the terminal and run `php -v`, if so, I can try to work on a solution.

Comment: It seems that they are just txt file. So you just have to parse them.

Answer (score 4):

With php you can do something like:

**extract.php**

```
<?php
$emails = array();

foreach(rglob("*.eml") as $eml){
    $emlContent = file_get_contents($eml);
    preg_match_all('/([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6})/i', $emlContent, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
        $emails[] .= $matches[1][$i];
    }
}


$emails = array_unique($emails);
print_r($emails);


function rglob($pattern='*', $flags = 0, $path='')
{
    $paths=glob($path.'*', GLOB_MARK|GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT);
    $files=glob($path.$pattern, $flags);
    foreach ($paths as $path) { $files=array_merge($files,rglob($pattern, $flags, $path)); }
    return $files;
}
```

---

**Usage:**

Place `extract.php` on the folder with the eml files and run from terminal `php extract.php`

Comment: This regex will extract only the "From" email addresses instead of including all the addresses (From, To, email content, ...)

preg_match_all('/From: =[^\n]+<([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6})>/i', $emlContent, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

Comment: The above code will extract any email address from the eml file.

Comment: You may want to adjust the regex to accept new tld's longer than 6 characters (`[A-Z]{2,6}`)

Comment: This regex for emails is very commonly used (and is the same as in your answer). I didn't find any official limit for tld's extensions, do you have a link?

I finally wrote my own script, will add a new answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same feature in a ready-to-use script so I wrote my own.

#### In a nutshell:

- Open extractor.php in your browser from a PHP server url
- Choose the folder on your hard disk where the .eml files are located
- Choose if you want to extract the addresses of senders, recipients, and/or from the content of the emails
- Click the Find email addresses button

The tool will analyze your folder recursively and show the email addresses in a textarea.

The **Email Address Extractor** is available on Github here:
https://github.com/migliori/email-address-extractor